# Question about involutions and projections

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection, orthogonal-matrices, involutions

In my course of Linear Algebra we were assigned the following problem:

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb F=\mathbb C$ with $\dim V<\infty$ and let $X \in \mathrm{O}(V)$ (i.e. an orthogonal matrix). Also, let $J$ be a linear operator on $V$ such that $J^2=-1$.

(a) Prove that the linear transform $\iota:X \mapsto -JXJ$ is an involution; that is, that $\iota^2 X=X$ for all $X \in \mathrm{O}(V)$.

(b) Define $T(X)=\frac{X-JXJ}{2}$. Prove that $T$ is a projection into $E_1$.

*Note: $E_{-1}$ and $E_1$ are the eigenspaces associated to the eigenvalues $\lambda=—1$ and $\lambda=1$, respectively.*

———————————

Part (a) of this problem is very straightforward, I just computed $\iota^2(X)$ and used the definition of $J$.

My problem is in part (b): I notice that $T(X)=\dfrac{1}{2}(X+\iota(X))$, but for some reason I can’t achieve the equality $T^2=T$.

And even if I manage to do that then how do I know that $T$ is a projection into $E_1$?
Do I need to find explicitly the set $E_1$?

**How can I find explicitly (if possible) the vector subspaces $E_{\pm 1}$? Since the orthogonal matrix $X$ is arbitrary then $\iota$ is also arbitrary.**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is the notation $E_1$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh $E_1$ is the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ of the involution. Thanks for pointing that out, I just included that in the question.

Comment: Regarding $T^2=T$: probably you can show that $T$ is linear ... how does that help you evaluate $T^2(X) = T(T(X))$?

Comment: As for the second goal: assuming you know that $V=E_1\oplus E_{-1}$ already, do you see that it suffices to show that (a) if $\iota(Y)=Y$ then $T(Y)=Y$, and (b) if $\iota(Y)=-Y$ then $T(Y)=0$?

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks, with your first comment, I did it, I proved that $T^2=T$.  Thank you. As for your second comment, I still don’t get it. Could you elaborate a little bit more, please? Mainly the part with $Y$.

Comment: I don’t see how $\iota(Y)=\pm Y$, and their consequences, help me in the last part :’(.